# Angular Use Global Service instead of decencies service

Tags: angular, angular-services

How can I have a shared service between an app and dependencies?

There is some pseudo code here but should get the point across.

```
module A imports service C (package says it is a dependency so it install it)

app Module B imports service C (to configure it)
```

I have a temp fix that is as follows, but dont like it since several dependencies might implement service c.

```
import {CService as OldCService} from 'c/node_modules/c';
import {CService} from 'c';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ... ], 
  providers: [
     {provide: OldCService, useClass: CService}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

The only other option i could see is to make service C optional (an be a peer dependency) ... However we were having issues getting optional to work with a forroot setup where it would be configured externally.

Comment: So, you are trying to use CService across your whole application, so all the components could share data through this service?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  CService is like a config service.  Therefore it needs to be configured by the app, then all the dependencies need to use the same instance to get the configuration.  With out my current fix they each have their own instance.

However I also want to be able to not configure the service and it still function (which is why i was researching optional).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This view I believe describes what i was wanting at the time:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBSnsNHQYo4